# Is the execution time for bcrypt independent of the length of the input string?

Tags: hash, bcrypt

Is the execution time for bcrypt independent of the length of the input string?

i.e.

Should the execution time of

```
bcrypt.hashpw('input_string', bcrypt.gensalt(12))
```

and

```
bcrypt.hashpw('arbitrarily_longer_input_string', bcrypt.gensalt(12))
```

be *in theory* the same.

Is this a something that is guaranteed by the bcrypt algorithm, or is it implementation specific?

Comment: This seems to be more suitable for [Crypto.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I wasn't aware of the Crypto.SE. Thanks. Should I remove this question if I cross-post to there?

Comment: @mmcnickle wait for a mod to migrate it.

Comment: You don't need to worry about it, a moderator will take a look at it and perform the appropriate action.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Execution time in [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) does not depend on the input size; internally, the input string is padded into a *fixed-length* sequence of bytes, and that sequence is then used throughout the algorithm.

It would be a problem if execution time depended on input size, because the "cost factor" parameter is adjusted to make the execution time as high as is tolerable. The question is relevant, but, fortunately, bcrypt does not have this specific weakness.

**Note:** input passwords for bcrypt have a maximum size of a few dozen bytes. [There are ways around it](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6623/pre-hash-password-before-applying-bcrypt-to-avoid-restricting-password-length) which involves a pre-hashing step (that step would take a time proportional to the password size, but it would be muuuuuch faster so the time overhead would be negligible, unless you are in the habit of typing passwords of several *megabytes*, which is impressive but weird).

Comment: Ok, I just took a guess. This guy actually knew the answer. I deleted my answer because it was incorrect.