# Why does Microsoft limit password length?

Tags: passwords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I have a maximum password length?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6287/should-i-have-a-maximum-password-length)

According to a [recent TNW article](http://thenextweb.com/microsoft/2012/09/21/this-ridiculous-microsoft-longer-accepts-long-passwords-shortens/):

> Microsoft doesn’t like long passwords. In fact, the software giant not
>   only won’t let you use a really long one in Hotmail, but the company
>   recently started prompting users to only enter the first 16 characters
>   of their password.

This practice seems counter-productive.

Would they have made this decision based on a limitation or particular behaviour of their hashing algorithm?

Comment: ...  also Microsoft isn't a good security role model.

Comment: @Rook - You make that statement based on what exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound The fact that they limit passwords to 16 characters long.

Comment: @Dan - My password longer then 16 characters disagrees.

Comment: @Ramhound I tried to sign up this morning at https://signup.live.com and it explicitly states: "Your password can't be longer than 16 characters."  Try logging in with only the first 16 characters of your password, I bet it will work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Purely legacy reasons. They are working to increase it.

From: http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_live/b/windowslive/archive/2012/07/15/keeping-your-microsoft-account-more-secure.aspx (see comment made by Eric Doerr in response to @MondayBlues):

> Password length - We are working on increasing this. Unfortunately,
>   for historical reasons, the password validation logic is decentralized
>   across different products, so it's a bigger change than it should be
>   and takes longer to get to market. It's also worth noting that the
>   vast majority of compromised accounts are through malware and
>   phishing. The small fraction of brute force is primarily common
>   passwords like "123456" not due to a lack of complexity.

Comment: The first sentence is the answer I was looking for! Thanks. (I didn't consider my question a duplicate because I wasn't asking a theoretical question about a planned system, as the linked one does, but a practical question about one that already exists.)

Comment: I agree, disagree with moderators...not a duplicate to me.

Comment: @EricFleischman Could you paste a quote of the relevant parts in here, so the answer will remain valid even if the link dies?

Comment: @lszi: paste complete