# How to protect myself from cyberbullying?

Tags: privacy

I want to learn how can I protect my PC from getting hacked in order to protect myself from cyberbullying. There is an intruder who has hacked my system over the last 4 years.

He has hacked my all emails, websites I log on to and whatever when it is related to me being online. He has a team of friends and has professional links all over the world.

When I make an email from another computer, I don't know how he comes to know about it but he knows my minute credentials of my account information.

When I go on certain websites my internet suddenly disconnects. I have to connect and reconnect my modem at least 200 times a day.

Even if I choose to take legal action on him,he would be locked up for some 6 months in a prison,but I have other plans for him(sorry for openly threatening).

I haven't used any of my emails (except reading) from last 3 years,he knows every website I visit on and that is how he uses me.

And I know all this, because he has accepted all these things over our chat.

Someone has advised me that I will have to become hacker to prevent myself. Is there any way I can consult a good security expert or an institution,where would I find it.

I live in India.

Comment: By the way he probably knows that you have posted a question regarding the situation here, and will likely move to more careful and clever attacks which will be less likely to be detected and stopped using the methods suggested by the SO community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the information you provided, far from being specific, your problems can be caused by several issues.

- **Email and web application credentials** - The best suggestion here is to change **all** your passwords and use strong ones. A service like [LastPass](https://lastpass.com/) can help you using only un-guessable and un-brutable passwords. For further information about password strength, I suggest reading a couple of SE questions ([ONE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/144/how-long-should-the-password-be) and [TWO](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/xkcd-936-short-complex-password-or-long-dictionary-passphrase)).
- **Bank details** - More information about the matter would have been helpful in troubleshooting this one, but I think it's still a case of stolen credentials.
- **"He knows everything!"** - Depending on the information he has, this can be the result of stolen credentials (think email, Facebook or any other social application were you might have shared those information with trusted people). He may also have a keylogger or a backdoor installed on your system; I suggest you format your computer and install a proper antivirus ([AVG Free](http://free.avg.com/) worked fine for me) and run scans periodically. Keep your software up-to-date, as there are plenty of public exploits which can be easily used.
- **Sudden disconnections** - I have a hard time thinking how an attacker can exploit this (except annoying the victim), so I won't speculate about its causes. If it is indeed caused by your "enemy", the previous sugegstions should work for this problem aswell.

If you still don't feel safe, a couple more suggestions.

- **Cryptography is your friend** - Make a [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) volume with a strong password and store there all your sensitive files. Use [GPG](http://www.gnupg.org/) when you need to share sensitive files or information with other people.
- **Good sense goes a long way** - Don't download and install from untrusted sources. Install browser plugins to stop the execution of unwanted scripts. *Never put online any information you don't mind sharing.*

Answer (score 15):

1. format your system
2. get an Antivirus and Firewall
3. secure all your wifi networks
4. make a new email address or change EVERY detail in your email account especially password and security questions. Your password needs to be strong.
5. file a complaint with your local police office
6. Don't share any details with anyone.
7. stop doing drugs.

Comment: A big +1 for point 5 here. @Himanshu - do not follow up your 'other plans' - the police can do the right thing. You may break various laws if you try to go after him.

Comment: +1 for "format your system". If the attacker is able to learn your credentials in real time, he's probably got some kind of rootkit, RAT, or keylogger installed on your machine. Just blow away your OS and start over. Also, if you're running Windows, I'd consider looking into running some version of Linux. (Linux is not a security panacea by any means, but it might help.)

Comment: +1 for point 7 - Talk about paranoid. Usually in this situation the user is just using the same weak password everywhere so the dictionary hack bots keep taking the accounts.

Answer (score 4):

You really do not need to hire security professional in this situation. Since this "hacker" has accessed your email account[s], bank login, and knows what websites you visit then he either has infected one of your computers with a trojan/backdoor/keylogger or has hacked into your wifi and is sniffing your traffic. Answer these questions for me:

1. What type of security do you have on your wireless network?
2. Is your firewall active on all of your computers?
3. Do you have a commercial antivirus installed and actively monitoring/protecting your computers?

I really do not know what sort of problem you are facing without knowing the answers to these questions so if you would please respond to them I can help ypu better. There really is no need to learn (in detail) hacking in order to mitigate threats.

Comment: Thanks for the info.Well I use personal computer,not laptop.My system is not connected to wifi,I do not have any security over my wireless network(I don't know what kind of wireless network you are talking about.).2-No firewall is not active and I have only one system.3-I havn't installed any commercial antivirus.Well,Bhubhu I just want to get rid of him controlling my internet activity,the websites I log on to,seizing email accounts.To simplify,like I don't know what you do on internet,with whom you interact on emails and other of my personal internet activities.

Comment: Well that's your problem. No firewall or antivirus means that he probably has infected your computer and has installed a trojan/backdoor from which he monitors all of your activity. Install the free program malwarebytes and run a scan.

Answer (score 3):

Something that you might consider is that a person (for all intents and purposes) really only needs to be able to access your email in order to be able to access virtually everything else that you are registered with.  This is especially the case if you have only one email address for everything.

Also, some email providers (I know Yahoo, for sure was this way in the past and probably still is) get "hacked" constantly.  There is really no hacking involved in the sense you are familiar with.  The security measures to reset the email password involve using some handy security question that is supposed to be personal.  With as much information as people post around the internet nowadays, you can find the answers to most peoples' security questions without much effort.  So every time you change the password, they simply use the reset tool and change it right back to whatever they like.

You should really secure your wireless network though (you can google it by the make and model of your router, if you are able to find that)