# Why did I get unresponsive script when I start my system and open web browser?

Tags: attacks, malware, known-vulnerabilities, timing-attack

The script on opening web broswersays Warning: Unresponsive Script

A script on this page may be busy,or it may have stopped responding.You can stop the script now,or you can continue to see if the script will complete.
Script:chrome//global/content/bindings/text.xml34
and then two options to continue & stop the script.
BTW my system is already hacked,and I have been cyber bullied by a hacker,is it related to that.

Comment: Have you tried setting your homepage to `about:blank`?

Comment: Just remove the infection....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*BTW my system is already hacked,and I have been cyber bullied by a hacker,is it related to that.*

Compromised systems should be **Nuked from Orbit** and reinstalled/restored from backup. So if you haven't done that it *might* be related. It would also mean you  still haven't done [what we suggested](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13884/how-to-protect-myself-from-cyberbullying/13899#13899) so please do this first.

If you have followed my steps, it might just be a defective plugin/addon in your browser.

Disable all your addons  and re-enable (make sure it's a plugin you installed) them one by one and restart your browser every time to identify the particular plugin. If the problem still persists this might be related.

Comment: I'd go a step further and not do a restore from backup unless I can be 150% certain that the backup wasn't compromised as well. Since I rarely can find that out, I would nuke and reinstall from start.