# A new Facebook password reset bug?

Tags: attacks, facebook

Based on [this](https://hackernoon.com/how-i-could-have-hacked-multiple-facebook-accounts-d9d335188d9b#.qooe4gfbl) and [this](http://fossbytes.com/how-to-hack-facebook-accounts-exploiting-password-reset-bug/) articles, the writer claims to be able to compromise about **2 millions accounts** by using reset code feature, and brute forcing the 6-digits reset code.

I have to main questions about that regardless of the truth about the attack:

- Is making the reset code much bigger will help resolving the problem, or Facebook will need a new reset technology?
- How to defend from this attack, should I reset it again after I receive the reset message from the attacking process, or should I reset via mail?

**Edit:**

Credit: @Dog eat cat world.

Just to clarify the problem,the attacker instead of bruteforcing users with a certain reset code, he's bruteforcing the code to a large scale users.

Comment: Length will increase entropy, so yes. Facebook can (and to my knowledge they do) limit the time between request and total number of failed attempts.

Comment: This bug reminds me of:
http://www.theverge.com/2016/3/8/11179926/facebook-account-security-flaw-bug-bounty-payout
Instead of bruteforcing users with a certain pin, it allowed you to bruteforce the pin to a certain user.

Comment: It's not many failed attempts to one account, he's testing some code on a large users scale.

Answer (score 2):

The weakness here the lack of Entropy in the password reset code.

I mean that you choose a random 6 digit number(338625), and try it against many users. So the attacker has to guess a reset code from `10^6` possibilities.At some point it may work.

**Calculation:** Since Facebook has a large user base and receives large number password reset requests say 10000 (`10^4`) in 3 minutes before they expire , which is comparable to `10^6`.

The probability that this password rest code is valid against some user is `0.01` .

> Is making the reset code much bigger will help resolving the problem,
>   or Facebook will need a new reset technology?

Facebook can simply fix it by increasing the entropy of password reset code.
This can be done easily by :

- Having Alphabets( `[A-Z|a-z]`- *52*),Digits( `0-9`-*10*),Special characters(*say 10* ) in the password reset code.
- Having a good length of say [10 characters](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/144/how-long-should-the-password-be) (Answer by Rоry McCune).

**Calculation:** For a reset code of length of 6,the attacker now have to guess a reset code among `(52+10+10)^6` .

The probability that this reset code randomly chosen by attacker matches a valid password reset code among the above `10^4` is `0.000000071` or `7.1*10^-8`. Instead of doing this, the attacker have better chances of guessing password itself and trying it against many users.

> How to defend from this attack, should I reset it again after I
>   receive the reset message from the attacking process, or should I
>   reset via mail?

I think efforts to secure against this attack should come from Facebook.

Since, users may not look in to the reset message/email as soon as it arrives. From user point of view all i can think is of enabling Two Factor Authentication.